# How to solve REST API with oAuth 1.0 Return 404 error in Magento 1.9.2.3?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, rest-api, oauth, postman

**Workout:**

**Version : Magento  1.9.2.3**

1. Created Rest **oAuth Consumer**
2. oAuth 1.0 installed in Server
3. Got the **Token Key, Token secret** using Consumer key & Consumer secret which created in **step 1**

**Note : I am using CDN**

**POSTMAN:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below url, its problem with your url :

```
https:example.com/index.php/api/rest/customers?limit=2
```

**hope its work for you**